# Requests in Asyncio - Keyword Arguments

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio

I'm using *asyncio* with the *requests* module to make an asynchronous HTTP request.

I can make a GET request like this:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def do_checks():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    req = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, 'https://api.github.com/user')
    resp = yield from req
    print(resp.status_code)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(do_checks())
```

However, I need to do support Basic HTTP Auth ([described here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/api/?highlight=auth#requests.Request.auth)) in the request.

According to the documentation, *url* and *auth* are both named parameters for requests.get().

But, if I run this (note the addition of **url=''** and **auth = ''**):

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def do_checks():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    req = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, url='https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
    resp = yield from req
    print(resp.status_code)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(do_checks())
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: run_in_executor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'url'
```

In the prototype for asyncio.run_in_executor(), additional arguments are supported:

```
BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor(executor, callback, *args)
```

requests.get() clearly supports named parameters (get, auth, etc.). What's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two ways to do that. Create a wrapper function, or just use a session to provide the auth.

Using a session:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def do_checks():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')
    req = loop.run_in_executor(None, session.get, 'https://api.github.com/user')
    resp = yield from req
    print(resp.status_code)
```

Writing a wrapper function (note that I'm using `def` for clarity here, but that a `lambda` would obviously work too):

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def do_checks():
    def do_req():
        return requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    req = loop.run_in_executor(None, do_req)
    resp = yield from req
    print(resp.status_code)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The session method worked for me. If I use the wrapper function, I can't figure out how to use do_req() in a for loop to call multiple different URLs without redefining do_req() each time (since I can't pass in the URL as an argument).

Comment: @user3689902 Just redefine a new function every time. Doing this with a lambda is quite lightweight.

Comment: The asyncio docs recommend using `functools.partial`, "because asyncio can inspect functools.partial() object to display parameters in debug mode, whereas lambda functions have a poor representation."

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio-pass-keywords

Answer (score 9):

This is actually a design decision in `asyncio`. From the docstring of asyncio/base_events.py:

```
"""Base implementation of event loop.

The event loop can be broken up into a multiplexer (the part
responsible for notifying us of IO events) and the event loop proper,
which wraps a multiplexer with functionality for scheduling callbacks,
immediately or at a given time in the future.

Whenever a public API takes a callback, subsequent positional
arguments will be passed to the callback if/when it is called.  This
avoids the proliferation of trivial lambdas implementing closures.
Keyword arguments for the callback are not supported; this is a
conscious design decision, leaving the door open for keyword arguments
to modify the meaning of the API call itself.
"""
```

Note the last sentence there.

The [asyncio PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/#callback-style) notes this as well, and recommends a lambda to work around it:

> This convention specifically does not support keyword arguments.
>   Keyword arguments are used to pass optional extra information about
>   the callback. This allows graceful evolution of the API without having
>   to worry about whether a keyword might be significant to a callee
>   somewhere. If you have a callback that must be called with a keyword
>   argument, you can use a lambda. For example:
>
> `loop.call_soon(lambda: foo('abc', repeat=42))`